# How to configure Provider Settings in Administer Website tool

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I am developing a website which is for my group of people and we provide certain services and conduct some programs and anyone can visit the website to see what is the latest info, contact us etc., So now I have added a folder in the solution named **Admin** and in that folder Admin.aspx page is present and based on the login info the page can be accessed and in that page any updates to the website like adding image to the gallery, programs for next month etc., can be done.

Now I have added a login.aspx page in the solution and I have added asp:login control to that page. I found an option named Administer Website in the same and I have provided all the configurations required like adding user, providing roles **> [as there is only one role i.e. admin]** etc., My website does not require any login but since I keep on need to update it I need some admins to login and insert data into database.

Now in that Administer Website tool in the Provider will appear as shown below:

[image]

and when I click on the Link **Test** it will display the below error:

[image]

and as per the instructions given in the error message I have configured my database by using aspnet_regsql.exe wizard with same database and connectionstring. But still I am getting that error. Can anyone Help me on this.

My webconfig file is as below:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
    <add key="Error" value="Page Error" />
</appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=F:\Studies\III MCA\VI SEM\Practice\MCB\App_Data\MCB.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <trace enabled="true" mostRecent="true" />
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="" />
    <authentication mode="Forms" />
    <roleManager enabled="true">
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"/>
  <pages><controls><add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" /></controls></pages>

</system.web>
```

I am using VS2012 express for web. Please help me if anyone knows what changes I have to make.

**

**Edited**
Now I am using Asp.Net Universal Provider but still I am getting the same error message. Really this one's causing me headache.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are using legacy ASP.Net Membership Provider.

Here is the new [ASP.NET Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx).

Then, you need to configure Membership Provider (see in the Scott Hanselman's article).

Comment: The error is basically application cannot find the database. Could you host the Database out side of the application (using SSMS), and update the connection string? If still not working, please post the new web.config.

Comment: @Win.. Its working now bro.. Thanks alot.. I added Provider Settings manually in asp.net and then the connection was success in Administrator tools too,... Thanks for your reply.. :)